# how to print the multidimensional array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is array value

```
 $value = Array (
      [0] => Array (
        [A] => -33.884667407851
        [F] => 151.16123199463
      ) 
      [1] => Array (
        [A] => -33.876686661215
        [F] => 151.20414733887
      )   
    )
```

This is my array and i want the output like this

[ [-33.866139529765626,151.26079559326172],[-33.866139529765626,151.26903533935547] ]

Comment: You question is unclear, every array value has a key.

Comment: Please show your code with your current output and what you would expect to get? (@Daan Seems like we are on a killstreak of unclear questions :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Totally agree.

Comment: Above is a array and my needed output is i given below.

Comment: So you just want to print the array ?! If yes where is the problem? Without code the array won't get printed

Comment: What are all the answers? Doesn't the OP just want to print $value without the [0] and [1]? So basically loop through $value and print all?

Comment: @Loko Nobody knows and from the different interpretation of the question it shows how unclear it is.

Comment: OP is looking for `json_encode()`, for converting PHP latitude and longitude array to javascript i guess

Comment: @Viral There is the problem: *i guess* <- You shouldn't have to guess a question, because then you play Russian roulette. A question should be so clear, that everyone understands the same thing under it. (And as you can see here, that is not the case here)

Comment: @Rizier123 i had to google `Russian roulette` meaning, but nvm, my first thought was json after seeing the output OP has posted, i guess you are right, i will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: ok fine i thought im asking wrong question.. finally this is my questiosn and  got answer to $your_array = array (
  0 => array (
    'A' => -33.884667407851,
    'F' => 151.16123199463
  ) ,
  1 => array (
   'A' => -33.876686661215,
    'F' => 151.20414733887
  )   
);

Comment: If you find any answer helpful, don't put comment here, instead mark the answer as accepted by green check mark on the left side of the answer @Sekar.G

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick,

```
$your_array = array (
  0 => array (
    'A' => -33.884667407851,
    'F' => 151.16123199463
  ) ,
  1 => array (
    'A' => -33.876686661215,
    'F' => 151.20414733887
  )   
);


$your_output = json_encode(array_map('array_values', $your_array));
```

Output:

```
[[-33.884667407851,151.16123199463],[-33.876686661215,151.20414733887]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (where `$foo` is your starting array):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($foo as $arr) {
    $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        array_push($new_arr, $val);
    }
    array_push($result, $new_arr);
}

print_r($result);
```